# How to have a unique local storage variable for different users in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an app using ionic framework. I have an array that i store locally using ngStorage... my problem when i logout i have to clear the $localStorage.SomeArray so that the when logged in as a different user, that user won't inherit the $localStorage.SomeArray. Is there a way to that

Comment: I wouldn't store anything that could give anything about a user away permanently in localStorage. That includes but is not limited to userids.

Comment: could you use sessionStorage instead? that goes away when the tab is closed

Comment: sessionStorage is unique to each tab/window though. Using localStorage is fine, just as long as you clear all sensitive data when no user is logged in.

Comment: personally, i don't really like the idea of clearing localStorage. that kind of requirement is problematic in a world of tab crashes. if you're only keeping it around for the duration of a session, then sessionStorage makes more sense. still, `window.onunload=function(){localStorage.SomeArray='';}` should work to clear it when they leave the page, replace the unload event with a logout one if you can/need.

Answer (score 0):

> How to have a unique local storage variable for different users in Angularjs

Store it under some user-specific key, e.g.:

```
localStorage[userKey] = [/*...the array...*/];
```

Comment: So i can do this localstorage[localstorage.currentuser.id]??

Comment: @teddybear123: I can't see why you'd store your current user under localStorage, but if you did, yes (with the capital S in `localStorage`)).

Comment: Just the id so i could have different local storages for different id thats logged in thanks!!